# Pulling a date together with other information from Localstorage. Error on the date

Tags: angularjs, string, date, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm working on a pretty basic ionic app where I need to be able to save a simple array of objects for whenever the user relaunches the application. The objects contain various information, it's basically a to-do list but with a specific date.

Everything is working fine except it will not display the date when i relaunch/refresh the application and it gives me this error:

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'T22' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [2015-12-11T22:00:00.000Z | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'] starting at [T22:00:00.000Z | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'].

I tried googling it but couldn't find anyone with a similar problem. I really have no idea even where the problem lies, as the console doesn't point to any specific direction.

**JS**

```
app.service('StoreService',function($window){
  if(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("products")) === null) {

var products={
      items:[]
    };
  }
   else {

var products =JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("products"));

  }
 console.log(products);

 this.saveItem=function(item){
     products.items.push(item);
     window.localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
     console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("products")));
 };

 this.get=function(){
   return products;

 };

});

$scope.newItem = function(user) {
  $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
  var x = Math.random();
  $scope.id =
    { id : x };
  angular.extend($scope.master, $scope.id);
  StoreService.saveItem($scope.master);
  $scope.reset(user);

}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-repeat="things in product.items track by things.id | orderBy: 'date'" class="item item-text-wrap">
      <h3>{{things.text}}</h3>
      <p ng-bind="{{things.date}} | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></p>
      <h3>{{things.note}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a codepen of your problem. The information here is insufficient to understand. I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/mjunaidsalaat/pen/KzRyxv?editors=1010) from your code. please reproduce the error here and paste the updated codepen here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove double curly braces for things.date
and change
ng-bind="{{things.date}} | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"
to
ng-bind="things.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"